# Paged has a error when database is SqlServer 2000

Tags: subsonic3

var products = Product.GetPaged(1, 20);

error:

'ROW_NUMBER' ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think Subsonic supports paging for SQL Server 2000 (but I could be wrong). You'd need SQL Server 2005 or 2008.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing Subsonic uses a CTE or the ROWNUMBER() syntax. These are not supported in SQL2000